# does not implement methodSignatureForSelector Error: Keyboard Notifications

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to handle the keyboard notifications using a separate class.

Class-KeyboardHandling:

```
class KeyboardHandling{


class func addObserverKeyboardWillShow(){

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification){

    let duration = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double

    print(duration)
  }
}
```

MainVC:

```
class MainVC: UIViewController {

//MARK: Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var textInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomToolbar: UIToolbar!
@IBOutlet weak var toolbarBottonConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

//MARK: Variables
var toolBarIntialBottomConstraint: CGFloat!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    toolBarIntialBottomConstraint = toolbarBottonConstraint.constant
    KeyboardHandling.addObserverKeyboardWillShow()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
}
```

The implementation works perfectly when **addObserverKeyboardWillShow()** is **not** a class function.

I get the error otherwise

Error Screenshot (Xcode 8.0):
[image: Console O/P]

Can someone explain why the same?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code snippet, it works fine for me...

Comment: @AhmadF Just to add, the following is in a different class file and the function was called in a separate ViewController class. May I know how you ran the code?

Comment: well, again... copy paste the same exact code snippets and it works. What the compile error says?

Comment: @AhmadF Console O/P updated